# Stop apply when condition is met

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with 1,000 columns and 30 million sample rows. I need to perform some operations(lets say addition,multiplication etc.,) on each column. If some value in any column after operation changes to 0, then I need to stop applying operations further on remaining columns and rows. Also, I would like to know at which column and row it changed to 0.

I have used iterrows with a few checks, but there is a performance issue as there is lots of data. Also, is there any alternatives to apply, iterrows?

```
ID   PID     PC   TID
10   1005   8017  3
11   10335  5019  2
12   1000   8017  1
13   243    8870  1
14   4918   8305  3
15   9017   8305  3
```

Apply operations column-wise:

- Col1 subtract by 9.
- Col2 subtract by 1000.
- Col3 divide by 100.
- Col4 subtract by 1.

After doing apply on second column, 3rd value is 0 and then whole process should be stopped and return the 2nd column 3rd row.

Output: 
If Column wise operations are performed:

```
ID   PID    PC     TID
1    5      8017   3
2    9335   5019   2
3    0      8017   1
4    243    8870   1
5    4918   8305   3
6    9017   8305   3
```

If row wise operations are performed :

```
ID   PID    PC      TID
1    5      80.17   2
2    9335   50.19   1
3    0      8017    1
13   243    8870    1
14   4918   8305    3
15   9017   8305    3
```

Comment: Can you post a sample dataframe, as well as a desired output?

Comment: Sure. I will edit question.

Comment: If it's just those math operations, you probably can avoid calling `apply` and do the calculation in a vectorized way with boolean masks. Can't tell unless you provide a [mcve].

Comment: There are other operations involved like string replacement. Null strings and float,date values. These checks changes from column to column too depending on the datatype of the column.

Comment: I have edited the question now. @chrisz

Comment: probably you're better off with `intertuples`

Comment: @anishtain4 taking the running time into consideration, I see `itertuples` have more running time over `apply` operations and it has better over `iterrows`. I can do this with iterrows easily by putting a break if any(row) == 0 condition met. But, my point is how can I optimize running time.

Comment: It's a bargain against memory and computation time. If you have enough memory, then apply each condition to each column in a vectorized manner and compare the least index of the columns, if memory is an issue, then you have to deal with the long run time.

Comment: @VenkataGogu can you post the output for the rows you've given? how would the output look like?

Comment: @YOLO Sure I will do a edit on question itself.

Comment: @anishtain4, that's the reason why I posted this question. My whole intent for posting this question is to save runtime. I have already mentioned that in question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Considering how you have many more rows than columns, and that vectorized ops are so much faster, I'd suggest the following:

```
for c in df.columns:
    res = <apply function on df[c]>
    if (res != 0).all(): # No zero found
        df[c] = res
        continue
    # Zero found - apply only up to it.
    df[c] = res[(res != 0).astype(int).cumsum() == 0] # Apply up to first 0
    break
```

Comment: Your solution looks interesting. But, considering, my data is around 30 millions rows,  while doing apply function on df[c], can we break this loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution as I mention in the comment

```
df1=df.copy()
df['PID']-=1000;df['PC']/=9;df['TID']-=1;df['ID']-=9

s=df.eq(0).idxmax(axis=0)
s
Out[492]:
ID     0
PID    2
PC     0
TID    2
dtype: int64

for x ,i in s.iteritems():
    df.loc[i:,x]=df1.loc[i:,x]
```

Comment: I think in this case, we are going to apply operations on all columns, even I encountered zero, after df['PID'] -1000 gives 0 at 3rd row. My question is when certain element changed to 0, then I need to stop doing operations. I don't want to perform operations on remaining rows/columns.