# How to efficiently loop through same data frame twice in pandas with breaking upon reaching a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have to loop a data frame twice with two pointers where the first pointer starts from 0 to len(df) and the second pointer starts from the first pointer to len(df). It also breaks when a certain condition is met. So I tried the below approaches.

```
for upper_index,upper_row in df.iterrows():
    for index,row in df[(upper_index+1):len(data)].iterrows():
        if condition met:
           break


 for upper in df.itertuples():
        for inner in df.iloc[(upper.Index+1):].itertuples():
            if condition met:
               break


 for upper in df.values:
            for inner in df[(counter+1):].values:
                if condition met:
                   break
```

The condition met is two compare two rows (first, second pointer) column values and decide to break or not.

For the third method, the counter is a variable I keep to increment the first pointer index.

But surprisingly all methods are slow and take a lot of hours where my df is only 40,000 rows.

Is there a better way to do it?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The condition function takes two rows as input?

Comment: Without knowing what `condition met` is doing it isn't possible to say

Comment: related (but not duplicated): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358598/stop-apply-when-condition-is-met

Comment: Honestly, to the best of my knowledge you would be better off plugging the function in a regular old apply and just letting in run through the entire dataframe.

Comment: Note that you ask two questions here: how to efficiently loop over the dataframe, and how to do so with 'break'ing upon reaching a condition.